# Java script loop through array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, vue.js

**I have java script array of objects read from html table like below**
**depId** represent the row number,
**branchId** represent column number and **val** it linked with check box (vue js v-model)
**3*3 table data:**

```
 permissions=   [
    [{depId:1,branchId:1,val:true},{depId:1,branchId:2,val:true},{depId:1,branchId:3}],
    [{depId:2,branchId:1},{depId:2,branchId:2},{depId:2,branchId:3}],
    [{depId:3,branchId:1},{depId:3,branchId:2},{depId:3,branchId:3,val:true}]
    ]
```

**I need to send this data to axios API, but the data should be in below format**

```
data[0][branches][0]=1
data[0][branches][1]=2
data[0][department]=1  

data[1][branches][0]=3
data[1][department]=3
```

**I tried something like this but it have problems  (the data sent in wrong indexes)**

```
let data={};
   permissions.forEach((row, i) => {
      row.forEach((col, j) => {
        if (col["val"] === true) {
          data[`data[${i}][branches][${j}]`] = col.branchId;
          data[`data[${i}][department]`] = col.deptId;
        }
      });
    });
        console.log(data);
```

**how the loop should be to send the data in correct way?**

the current result is

```
"data[0][branches][0]": 1,
  "data[0][department]": 1,
  "data[0][branches][1]": 2,
  "data[2][branches][2]": 3,
  "data[2][department]": 3
```

Comment: `but it have problems` what are the problems?

Comment: the data sent in wrong indexes @JaromandaX

Comment: Yeah, first problem: your indexes are going from 1 to 3 instead of 0 to 2.

Comment: Is your re-referencing data construct "data[`data[${i}][branches][${j}]`]" really the way you want to do the job? I don't even want to understand that one... it's bad readability for sure.

Comment: The API built in this way @JanosVinceller

Comment: I don't see an API here, but it's still wrong, even if. I'd extract the inner part, like var branchId = `data[${i}][branches][${j}]`; and put it to the console. Then you got an overview, what data is going around.

Comment: And please put a semicolon at the end of each line, even the permission and the data part.

Comment: Also wrong: you've got no commas between the inner arrays in "permissions". And please put those property names (like branchId) into quotation marks.

Comment: @JanosVinceller  
sorry dear, i write the question as pain text,my code have your notes

Comment: @JanosVinceller
the problem  that "data[0][branches][0]": 1,
  "data[0][department]": 1,
  "data[0][branches][1]": 2,
  "data[2][branches][2]": 3,   instead of data[1]
  "data[2][department]": 3     instead of data[1]

Comment: I've read this question numerous times and I'm still totally lost in regard to what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Alex
i need to print the result like this
data[0][branches][0]=1
data[0][branches][1]=2
data[0][department]=1  
data[1][branches][0]=3
data[1][department]=3

Comment: That's why the question itself is not useful for the community. It was literally a compiling problem. The problem was, that the interpreter didn't show an appropriate message about the missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a couple of commas in your `permissions` object.
The next problem is that you were trying to check for `departmentId` in `permissions`, but it's actually `depId` there.
The next thing is that you do not need to define and track `i` and `j`, they are conveniently provided to you in a `forEach` function as the second argument that is passed to the running function.

Here is a working version of what you were trying to achieve:

```js
permissions = [
  [{
    depId: 1,
    branchId: 1,
    val: true
  }, {
    depId: 1,
    branchId: 2,
    val: true
  }, {
    depId: 1,
    branchId: 3
  }],
  [{
    depId: 2,
    branchId: 1
  }, {
    depId: 2,
    branchId: 2
  }, {
    depId: 2,
    branchId: 3
  }],
  [{
    depId: 3,
    branchId: 1
  }, {
    depId: 3,
    branchId: 2
  }, {
    depId: 3,
    branchId: 3,
    val: true
  }]
]

let data = {};
let j = 0;

permissions.forEach((row) => {
  let i = 0;
  let departmentSeen = false;

  row.forEach((col) => {
    if (col["val"] === true) {
      data[`data[${j}][branches][${i}]`] = col.branchId;
      data[`data[${j}][department]`] = col.depId;
      i++;
      departmentSeen = true;
    }
  });

  if (departmentSeen) {
    j++;
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: the data in this case should be 
 "data[0][branches][0]": 1,
  "data[0][department]": 1,
  "data[0][branches][1]": 2,
  "data[1][branches][0]": 3,
  "data[1][department]": 3

Comment: the data index should be sequence

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'the data index should be sequence', can you elaborate?

Comment: like this (from the example result)
 "data[1][branches][0]": 3, instead of "data[2][branches][2]": 3,
@IvanD

Comment: I edited the solution. Please note that output will have the different order of elements, but the elements are the same. Is it what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu,that what i need